# Instagram added x-frame-options DENY so their embed script stopped working?

Tags: iframe, instagram, embed

When you want to embed an instagram post to your website, instagram offers an embed button which effectively uses `<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>` and a blockquote to produce an iframe version of the post embeded into your own website.

Today found out instagram added a header x-frame-options:deny so their own script is not working any more.

Is this intended, how can you embed without the use of API a simple post any more ?
The error your get is

> The loading of [URL] in a frame is denied by “X-Frame-Options“
> directive set to “deny“

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found answer. Works for my method.
When you embed posts with insta copycode, you get in  url like:
instagram.com/p/xyz
When you copy it straight from url bar, its:
instragram.com/username/p/xyz

You need to get rid of /username/ and it might work again.